# Django mail not sending mail to def in views error

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, sendmail.exe

```
**views.py code**(views.py function id not call urls.py)
def SendMail(request,id):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug,status='published')
    form=EmailSendForm()
    return render(request,'mail.html',{'form':form,'post':post})

**models.py**(models.py not accept the id number in views.py)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
```

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(('draft','Draft'),('published','Published'))
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300,unique_for_date='publish')
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='post',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body=models.TextField()
    publish=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    objects=CustomManager()

class Meta:
        ordering=('-publish', )

def __str__(self):
        return self.title
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post',args=[self.publish.year,
                                     self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                     self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                     self.slug])
```

**urls.py**(urls show page not found 404 error)
    path('/(?P\d+)share/$',views.SendMail),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**views.py**
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from app.models import Post
from app.forms import EmailSendForm

def post_list_view(request):
    post_list=Post.objects.all()
    paginator=Paginator(post_list,3)
    page_number=request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        post_list=paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        post_list=paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        post_list=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'post_list':post_list})

def post_detail_view(request,year,month,day,slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug,
                           status='published',
                           publish__year=year,
                           publish__month=month,
                           publish__day=day,
                         )
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post':post})

def SendMail(request,post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id,status='published')
    sent=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=EmailSendForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd=form.cleaned_data
            subject='{}({})Please read message"{}"'.format(cd['name'],cd['email'],post.title)
            post_url=request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            message="Read Post at:\n {}\n\n{}\'s Comments:\n{}".format(post_url,cd['name'],cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject,message,'vpnraut@gmail.com',[cd['to']])
            sent=True
    else:
        form = EmailSendForm()
    return render(request, 'mail.html', {'sent':sent,'form':form, 'post':post})

**models.py**
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

from Django.urls import reverse
from Django.utils import timezone

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(('draft','Draft'),('published','Published'))
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=300,unique_for_date='publish')
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='post',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body=models.TextField()
    publish=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    objects=CustomManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-publish', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post',args=[self.publish.year,
                                     self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                     self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                     self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.EmailField()
    body=models.TextField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Commnted by {} on {}'.format(self.name,self.post)
**urls.py**
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.post_list_view),
 path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>/',views.post_detail_view,name='post'),
    path('(<int:post_id>\d+)/share/',views.SendMail, name='post_share'),]
```